# How to add image inside stack panel which is inside many xaml elements using C# code

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have a xaml page with several panorama items and one of the panorama's code is as below

```
 <phone:PanoramaItem Header="onepan">

      <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
      <StackPanel>
      <ListBox x:Name="PhoneList" Height="486" Background="{x:Null}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>

       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="108"  >
     <Image Height="100" Margin="5" Stretch="Fill" Width="100" Source="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" ></Image>
     <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="20,28,0,0"  Width="265" >
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <TextBlock x:Name="titles" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" LineHeight=" 24" MaxHeight=" 48" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Black" FontStyle="Normal" Text="{Binding title}" 
                                            Margin="0,0,0,0"  Tag="{Binding title}" Tap="navigateto"/>
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Margin="123,-3,0,0" Foreground="Black" FontStyle="Normal" Text="{Binding Date}" Height="27" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-4,0,3" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="date :" Width="118" Foreground="Black"/>
   <StackPanel x:Name="ivnod" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="28" Margin="0,21,10,-33" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255">
   <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Rating" Width="64" Foreground="Black"/>
   //I want to add here a image tag by c# code
    </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
     </ListBox>
       </StackPanel>
      </Grid>

 </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

I want to add image tag inside stack panel called 'ivnod' using for loop I can add images directly but I dont know whether I should specify all these elements before specifying stack panel and while using this code it displays error

```
  Image img = new Image();
  img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.Relative));
  ivnod.Children.Add(img);//-->here ivnod displayed as "not available in current context"
```

Comment: Image path is correct

Answer (score 2):

You should take `Image` control over there and you can pass `binding` to it as you are giving to `TextBlock`. you just need to pass `Source` to `Image` in Binding. that Would work Perfectly.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ivnod" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="28" Margin="0,21,10,-33" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255">
     <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Rating" Width="64" Foreground="Black"/>
     <Image Source="{Binding imgSource}"></Image>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: But How will I call image with name since there is number of image tags

Comment: when you would pass datacontext or itemsource at that time you would needed to add one more property to bind that image control so you are not needed to set image by calling its name. it would take from binding property

Comment: here is a link would help you out for understanding binding of data  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852595.aspx